# Best way for python debugging when using rest api

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'm creating an application which takes input(**Rest API**) from **postman** and after that doing some processing.

While doing some manipulation i want to use some debugger like ***pdb***.

Is there any debugger for such applications or what is the best way to debug such applications?

**Scenario:**

I have one server where python code is running and doing manipulation over there. After receiving the input from the postman(Rest API) it goes to server and executes that code. And here in python code I want to use some debugger like pdb, where i can see each and every variables value.

Comment: I do not exactly understand your question. Do you need remote debugging (e.g. for debugging REST API server)? Or do you want to debug some local (client) process that processes rest api result.

Comment: I don't know about remote debugging, i have updated the question in more detailed.

Comment: In your scenario: I understand you want to debug python code on mentioned server side, but do you want to use debugger on the same computer your server is running? Or is it other computer. Also do you want to attach to a process of server running in background or do you start this server in foreground for debugging reasons?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach to a server running in background (on another computer) that is actually **remote debugging** or **embedded debugging**. You can use [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/download/) debugger. And [here](http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/) is description how to use embedded debugging in winpdb.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I have a server but don't know where the process is running and how to attach it with pdb or Is there any other process to debug. I want to debug it from my local machine as in normal case i do ssh to the machine where process is running or simply restart it with pdb.

Comment: C'mon. In my answer you have info which debugger you could use for remote debugging and link to exact instruction how to do that. Did you read it at all?